# MongoDB - Add fields to the object in an array from another object array based on matching condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to write an aggregation in MongoDB which would result as shown below. Please suggest to me how to build MongoDB Aggregation in order to achieve my output.

Collection (input): I would like to add a key test_id to the obj.test_id object based on matching condition test_id.

Please suggest an optimal way of writing a MongoDB query to achieve my result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$set` - Set `dataObj.cFS.data` field.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate each element in `dataObj.cFS.data` and return a new array.

   1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge the current iterate object (`data`) with the result from *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. `$first` - Get the first filtered document from the result *1.1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1.1. `$filter` - Filter the document(s) from the `cfCoreData` array by matching the `cf_id`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "dataObj.cFS.data": {
        $map: {
          input: "$dataObj.cFS.data",
          as: "data",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$data",
              {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$cfCoreData",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$data.cf_id",
                        "$$this.cf_id"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kPHfmaUbfh-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!
This helps in my usecase!
Appreciate your help!